# Drupal 7 dpm an object, but not sure how to render a recursion variable?

Tags: 7, views

In Drupal 7 Views php. I'm trying to render and string replace the content:path field by using a global PHP views field. The issue I'm having is i'm not sure how to reference the content:path field as $row->path shows a NULL value. I can see that the content:path variable exists in the $view object, but it shows **recursion**. How would one render a recursion value to show up when I do a print?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you just need to dpm() or print_r() the recursion variable. Basically for the listed recursion variable that krumo displays, you just put in that variable inside dpm() to view inside the recursion variable. If you don't do this and just dpm() the parent of it, you'll get that recursion infinity sign. hope that makes sense.